# How to let javascript "breath"

Tags: javascript, jquery, freeze

I have some javascript/jquery code (for an internal website) that does a lot of client side processing on a large table. It runs a little slowly, but that's OK.

The problem is that it freezes the browser while running through the loops that it needs to do. This has two effects that are undesirable:

1. The processing spinner (an animated gif, but I also tried spin.js and that has the same issue) freezes.
2. If there are enough rows in the table, the loops take a long time and the browser reports an unresponsive script

Is there a way I can have some sort of a "breath" statement in the code, such that every (say) 100 iterations, it pauses to let the spinner spin and the browser know that the script is still working on it? Something like (pseudo code) :

```
for (i=0;i<20000;i++)
{
    fnProcessRow();
    if (i % 100 == 0) breath();
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post the pertinent code that you are having performance issues with? Perhaps that can be optimised first before considering other artifical "waiting" constructs

Comment: Yes, but only if you're using a self executing function instead of a for loop. You could also move this to a webworker in browsers that support it.

Comment: is it possible to do any of the processing on the server to lighten the load on the front end?

Comment: how about setting a Timeout with `setTimeout(callback(), interval)` on each 100th or so, interation?

Comment: @Zlatan That would delay every 100th iteration, but none of the ones between or after.

Comment: @KevinB, yea.. when I rethink about it, you're right!

Comment: You may also want to consider looking into web workers http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/, if you are willing to only support modern browsers.

Comment: If the interface is freezing, then I'll bet a pound to a penny your javascript is interacting with the DOM far more than necessary. Code can very often be optimised to do more in javascript and less in the DOM. Sorting a list for example - the slow approach is to shuffle elements around in the DOM - the fast approach is to sort an array of DOM references then rearrange the DOM elements when the final order is known.

Comment: unfortunately a lot of the code doing the actual processing is out of my control, so optimization is not possible. The processing is done via a callback which is also out of my control, so I can't use timeouts to batch process the callbacks.

Comment: @BenHolness If you can't control the code... there isn't anything you can do to control how it operates.

Comment: @KevinB - to expand on that, I have access to the callback, which calls another (out of my control) function to do the processing, but I can't batch the callback. I could put in something before the call to the processing function that says "if record number % 100 == 0 then breath" (if I could find such a function).

Comment: Right, but there is no way of allowing it to "breath" without delaying the execution of all next iterations by n, which you can't do from a callback unless it's built into the code itself, for example, the way jQuery's .queue works. (though that won't be useful here either).

Answer (score 1):

One way to break up your javascript is to divide your processing into chunks and use setTimeout() to perform the next "chunk"

Let me know if you need some code to show you what I mean.

Comment: unfortunately this is not possible in this situation as I do not have control of the processing code to do this, unless the chunk size is 1 :)

Comment: If you can't break up the processing into smaller bits then you're only resort is to use web workers. This would therefore not make it compatible with all browsers out there (at the moment, anyway)

Answer (score 1):

There is no set method for doing this as it depends very specifically on your code.  Something like this would work:

```
fnProcessRows(0, 10000);

function fnProcessRows(start, end) {
    /* do row processing */

    if (end < totalRows) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            fnProcessRows(start + 10000, end + 10000);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

This will process 10000 rows with a one second break in between.  This can have potentially weird side effects like displaying the "processed" rows with "unprocessed" rows, which may be undesirable.  If it's not, then this should be a pretty simple solution to help out.

You can of course reduce 10000 to something else if it's *still* unresponsive; it should be unresponsive for only very short periods of time that the user would have a hard time noticing.

Comment: Unfortunately (not clear from my simplified example) the processing is done via a callback which is also out of my control, so I can't use setTimeouts to batch process the callbacks. I could use a setTimeout on each call though, that might work.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123623/674326).

If you do not want to go the setTimeout/setInterval route, try adding:

```
if (i % 100) { $("selector for your animated image").width(); }
```

On some (most?) browsers that will force it to re-layout and render.