# manipulate text of an element in $each function

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, each

I'm trying to display the passing of an object in the $each loop in percent for the user.
In the console I see the correct values but in the frontend the content of the item is not displayed until the $each loop is done and then it says 100%.

```
<div id="editForm-loader">
   <p><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Daten werden geladen <i class="info"></i> <input type="text" value="" class="info"></p>
</div>



success: function(response) {
  var aData   = JSON.parse(response).data;
  var count   = 0;
  var loading = 0;
  var rows    = Object.keys(aData).length;
  $.each(aData, function(key, value) {
    count++;
    loading = Math.round((count*100)/rows);
    $('#editForm-loader i.info').text(loading + '%');      // nothing changes in the frontend 
    $('#editForm-loader input.info').val(progress + '%');  // to test, but also does not change
    console.log($('#editForm-loader i.info').text());      // show the correct value

    // at this point I do a lot with the data
    // so the each function with over 100 items takes about 5 seconds total.

  });
  $('#editForm-loader').hide();
}
```

the hint that it should be executed in an ajax success callback

It seems like the rendering is blocked in time

[SOLVED]

```
success: function(response) {
  var aData     = JSON.parse(response).data;
  var count     = 0;
  var loading   = 0;
  var items     = Object.keys(aData).length;
  var aFields   = [];
  for (var key in aData) {
    aFields.push({'key': key,   'val': aData[key]});    // It is an assoc array, so I am writing it again to be able to access it with count.
  }

  var iV  = setInterval(function() {
    loading  = Math.round(((count+1)*100)/items);
    $('#editForm-loader i.info').text(loading + '%');
    var key   = aFields[count].key;
    var value = aFields[count].val;

    // at this point I do a lot with the data
    // so the each function with over 100 items takes about 5 seconds total.

    if (++count >= items) {
      clearInterval(iV);
      $('#editForm-loader').hide();
    }
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: probably the loop runs only few milliseconds ? A code snippet would be nice

Comment: I have extended my code a little bit again. It runs for about 5 seconds and in the console I see exactly the % value and that looks good. When I query the content of the element it also looks very good.

Just not visible to the user.

Comment: hmn for me this is really hard to answer because I cant figure out how to reproduce this. Maybe you can try to replace .text() with vanilla js, eg `$('#editForm-loader i.info')[0].textContent = loading+'%'` to verify its actually a problem of jquery or sth else

Comment: Hello @johnSmith,
thanks for the tip, I have tested it and unfortunately it does not work either.

Comment: i´d say the cause is still that the loop only takes few miliseconds and due to the asynchronous nature of js you get the imagination to see the console logs as they should be, which is really dependant to what is "i do a lot with this data"

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't manage to create a small test environment that runs as long as the original, so that you can see the problem.

But regardless of the percentage.
No text manipulation is shown in the frontend until the $each function is completely finished.

Comment: you will find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123553/how-do-i-update-the-html-displayed-for-each-iteration-of-a-for-loop-in-javascrip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the html displayed for each iteration of a for loop in javascript / jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123553/how-do-i-update-the-html-displayed-for-each-iteration-of-a-for-loop-in-javascrip)

Comment: Hello John,

Thank you very much. It wasn't quite trivial, but I came up with a working solution via setIntervall.

I will now also give you the code snippet in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout()` and increment the delay every iteration of the loop.

Simplified example:

```js
const data = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 100]

$.each(data, function(i, value) {
  setTimeout(function() {    
    $('#editForm-loader i.info').text(value + '%');
  }, i * 500)// 1/2 second increments
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="editForm-loader"><i class="info"></i></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answerbut unfortunately, setTimeout does not help. In your example the element is also only updated when the object has been passed through completely and not after each item.

Example the object has 50 items. Then after one 2% should be displayed after two 4% after three 6% etc.